# Visual Studio Custom Go To Definition

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, go-to-definition

Assuming a solution containing two web project ("A" and "B"), which "A" loads in "B", and "B" is the presentation layer.

So when HTML file in project "A" addressing a JavaScript file located in project "B", then by firing Go To definition (F12) command, it look-ups for the address from the "A" project root address, and return nothing.

But the script file is located in "B" project which is work fine when the project runs, but inside Visual studio, it can't find the file.

> So far I know that this is a correct logical behavior.

Anyhow, is there any magic way to change "Go To definition" command behavior and make it able to search using some sort of addressing pattern per project?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @Cristy Not even in vs 2017